# PyQt5 on Windows

Tags: pyqt5

I have the Python 3.6 and Qt 5.8 on my Windows, I want to install PyQT5.

I downloaded

sip-4.19.zip

and

PyQt5_gpl-5.7.1

and I don't know what should I do next

I've found some posts talking about "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012" but I didn't install VS2012 on my PC. should I install it first ?

Comment: [Installing PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html).

Answer (score -1):

Using pip as follows should do the trick:

```
pip install PyQt5
```